# Becoming 1099 consultant with most recent company?

Tags: new-job, contracts, notice-period, consulting

I has been working as a senior software developer with my most recent company for almost 4 years, 2 with group A and then 2 with group B. A week after submitting my 2 weeks notice to group B, group A asks me to come and help them with one of my old projects (for which I was the only developer) and asks me if I can start working for them as a 1099 consultant to address some of their existing bugs and to add several new feature.

How should I approach this potential offer to work as 1099 employee while working at my new job?
And what is reasonable pay for 1099? Should it be higher than what they been paying me (or what I am getting at my new job) since I will not have benefits and health insurance from the company? If higher, but what amount (% wise).

Answer (score 3):

Are they competitors?  If so, then I'd avoid it, it will bring you into conflicts of interest.  If they aren't, you're free to do what you want on your own time.  I would set the expectations with them that they are the 2nd priority, so they understand that.  And be very honest with yourself about what you can and can't take on and get done without burning yourself out or sacrificing too much of your time to be happy.

As for what to ask for pay wise-  that's up to you.  Ask for enough that you'd rather have the money than the free time.  That's really what it comes down to.

Answer (score 2):

> How should I approach this potential offer to work as 1099 employee
>   while working at my new job?

Approach it as you would any side gig.

Decide if you want to do it. And if so, decide how much time you want to devote to it. (Remember, you have a primary job and you want to start that off on your best foot. Don't starve your "real" job to feed your "side" job.)

As for pay, you seem to have some leverage here.

You should be able to get your prior salary easily. And it wouldn't be much of a stretch to get your prior salary plus the cost of the extra taxes you must pay as a 1099 contractor. You would have a decent argument to ask for your salary at your new job too.

As far as benefits, I assume you'll be getting those through your new employer and don't need them through your 1099 gig.

Make sure your new company won't have a problem with you working on the side.